# Why Entry interface defines methods like equals and hashCode?

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I saw that interface java.util.Map.Entry has methods:

```
boolean equals(Object o);
int hashCode();
```

Why are above methods a part of `Entry` interface when same methods are inherited from the `Object` class?

Thanks and Regards,
Rahul

Comment: Because they are required to have different implementations? As documented?

Comment: i don't see any valid reason for marking the question as down ? Node implements the Map.Entry and it can override the equals and hashCode, even if it is not declared in the Entry interface ? my question is simple what is the point of these declaration in Entry interface?

Comment: I've answered that. It is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) why. Read it.

Comment: @EJP no, you did not. Check the Map.Entry interface

Comment: @EJP even if you add them to any interface, you are still not forced to override because they are inherited from `Object`. OP phrased his question poorly but it's clearly not "why do we override stuff"

Comment: @GrzegorzPiwowarek The second sentence of my original comment addresses that. Keep reading.

Comment: @EJP if people have problems reading your "answer", maybe it's a sign that you should prepare a comprehensive one? for now, it qualifies only for rude/low-quality answer flag.

Comment: @GrzegorzPiwowarek It was posted as a comment, not an"answer". I consider it trivial, as it is already documented. Both answers here already say the same thing. If you have problems reading as far as two sentences, you aren't ready for what I have to offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three points to consider:

- from a **technical** perspective this is not necessary: every class inherits these two methods from the `Object` class. Adding these two methods to an interface technically adds nothing
- from an **implementation** perspective: these definitions do not "override" the definitions of the class `Object`. You can therefore implement this interface without writing your own implementations.
- from the **documentation** perspective: the documentations for [`Map.Entry.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) and [`Map.Entry.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#hashCode--) have very specific requirements on what these methods should do in any implementation of the interface.

You could put the documentation about the requirements for these two methods into the general documentation of the interface, but that would make it a lot harder to find (and read) that documentation.

Ideally, someone looking up the interface would see that it declares these two methods, get curious and read the interfaces documentation of these two methods and then gets a hint on what he should do to properly implement these to methods in classes that implement the interface.

Answer (score 4):

As the overriding defintion says; It is used when a class that extends from another class wants to use most of the feature of the parent class and wants to implement **specific** functionality in certain cases.
 And the oracle documentation for boolean equals() says;

> This ensures that the equals method works properly **across different implementations of the Map.Entry interface.**

So for the specific implementation of equals() method the `boolean equals(Object o)` and `int hashCode()` are overridden.

Comment: that's not the answer to the question. The OP is aware how overriding works but he does not understand why duplicate method signatures in another interface when you are guaranteed to have them because they come from Object

Comment: as per your answer "This ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the Map.Entry interface."  Please let me know what will go wrong if i remove the hasCode and equals method declaration from the Entry interface.

Comment: Sir as the documentation says for the proper implementation across different diaspora of `Map.Entry` interface and as the equals() method of Object class has restrictions and ambiguity.

Comment: @rbhawsar What goes wrong is that it is no longer documented what they are required to do.

Comment: No Sir(@rbhawsar), please look at this code: 
`(o instanceof Map.Entry)
&& (getKey() == null ? ((Map.Entry) o).getKey() == null
                     : getKey().equals(((Map.Entry) o).getKey()))
&& (getValue() == null ? ((Map.Entry) o).getValue() == null
                       : getValue().equals(((Map.Entry) o).getValue()))`    and do tell me how the **getKey().equals()**  will work if `equals()` method would have been from `Object` Class?

Comment: @Mandy8055 You're missing one point. It doesn't matter whether a Map.Entry implementation implements its own (semantically conformant) equals/hashCode or inherits Object's versions: both will compile without error (of course the latter will cause strange runtime behaviour). And the "correct code" is only given as a documentation hint in Map.Entry's javadoc. Won't come into action unless you copy it into your own methods.

Comment: I completely agreed with you Sir(@Ralf Kleberhoff) but the runtime behaviour as I mentioned above would be ambiguous therefore the developers have declared it for `Map.Entry` interface also

Answer (score 2):

It's just to have a place for Javadoc.

Declaring `equals()` and `hashCode()` in an interface doesn't force the implementing class to implement any of them. The methods inherited from `Object` fulfill the interface's *technical* requirement (but not the semantics needed within Maps).

`Map.Entry` needs a specific equals/hashCode behaviour, and so the Java designers chose to redundantly declare them as part of the `Map.Entry` interface and place the Javadoc there explaining how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rule of thumb that if you are going to override one of the methods( **i.e. equals() or hashCode()** ) , you have to override both of them otherwise it is a violation of contract made for equals() and hashCode(). Please refer to the [Oracle's java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)  for the method’s contract.

**Thus, Entry interface overrides these both methods for specific functionality.**

Moreover,if you(or **Entry interface**) don't override a class's **equals()** method,

> you won't be able to use those objects as a *key* in a *hashtable*
>
> and you probably won't get accurate *Sets* such that there are no
>   conceptual duplicates.

**Also,**

> The **equals()** method in class **Object** uses only the **==**
>   operator for comparisons, so unless you override equals(), two objects
>   are considered equal only if the two references refer to the same
>   object.

If you look into the source code of Object class you will find the following code for the equals() method.

```
  public boolean equals(Object obj) 
{
    return (this == obj);
}
```